# Spring Integration http outbound gateway POST restful call with JSON

Tags: spring-integration

I tried to make a POST restful api call from Spring Integration with http:outbound-gateway.  But I couldn't figure out how to pass the request JSON object to the restful API. Can someone show me how to do it?  Thanks !

Here is my spring-integration-config.xml

```
<si:channel id="request.channel" />

<si:channel id="response.channel">
    <si:queue capacity="10" />
</si:channel>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="employeeinfoGateway"
    request-channel="request.channel" 
    url="http://localhost:8080/EmployeeInfo"
    http-method="POST" 
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String" 
    charset="UTF-8"
    reply-timeout="5000" 
    reply-channel="response.channel">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Here is my Java code:

```
MessageChannel request = (MessageChannel) context.getBean("request.channel");       

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("empId", "100");

    request.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(obj).setHeader("content-type","application/json").build());
```

Here is the error message I received:

```
Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.json.JSONObject] and content type [application/json], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"empId":"100"}, headers={content-type=application/json, id=a0aba65f-3f49-4dfc-2431-51983666772b, timestamp=1521419315405}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is that `JSONObject`. Seems for me that's not how Jackson JSON processor works, but I would suggest to try to send just a plain `java.util.Map` instead.

There is a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in the `RestTemplate` underneath to convert incoming payloads to a JSON representation.

Maybe you just don't have a `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` jar in your classpath?

Comment: I tried to pass a java.util.Map into the message payload and it did not work.

Comment: OK! Do you have Jackson jar on the classpath to let `RestTemplate` to do the hard work for the JSON ?

Comment: Yes, it works.  Thanks, Artem.  I added jackson-databind jar and then pass a java.util.Map to message payload.